# Running async task after activitiy

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I want to ensure that the async task that i started in android activity will be completed when i moved to another activity .

I think it will.

Please provide correct answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

async task is a background process which can run or stoped by activity but it does not run in activity it run in background also run after activity finishes so ur will run when u go to another activity.

Answer (score 0):

Asyntask runs in a background process so it will run even if the activity is finished but make sure if the activity is finished you are not interacting with any of the elements of activity or it will cause problem in asynctask when the activity is finished